# Access to the same I18nContext from bundled components

Tags: reactjs, vite, react-i18next

as mentioned in the title, I have a bundled UI kit and I would like to enable translation within the UI kit, as some of its molecule components require translations. I have tried to use the useTranslation hook to access the i18n config object, but it returns undefined. I also attempted to include it as an external in my ViteJS bundler, but I still get undefined i18n. I would like to ask if anyone else has had the same requirements and how they were able to achieve this. Thank you very much.

I tried using the useTranslation hook to access the i18n instance inside bundled components, but I received undefined. I'm expecting to receive the i18n instance object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was testing my UI-kit with the `yarn link` command, which links the `node_modules` folder into my main project. This created two `react-i18next` Provider instances which prevented the bundled code from accessing the main Provider.

To resolve my issues, I used `yalc` to install my package locally. Unlike `yarn/npm`, yalc only copies the files specified in `package.json`, instead of symlinking all the folders.

For everyone have the same issue even using yalc on local environment. Control if react-i18next entry is put on bundler externals